# How to dequeued messages from a Activemq queue?

Tags: queue, activemq-classic, mqtt, virtual-topic

I'm using the Virtual Topics concepts of Activemq 5.14.5 (https://activemq.apache.org/virtual-destinations) with MQTT protocol.
ActiveMQ will pick up the messages written to the topic and write them to a queue (or multiple queues or topics). See the ${ACTIVEMQ_HOME}/conf/activemq.xml configuration below:

```
   <beans>
       <broker>
           ...  
           <destinationInterceptors>
            <virtualDestinationInterceptor> 
              <virtualDestinations> 
                <compositeQueue name="MY.QUEUE">
                  <forwardTo>
                    <queue physicalName="FOO" /> 
                    <topic physicalName="BAR" />
                  </forwardTo>
                </compositeQueue>
              </virtualDestinations>
            </virtualDestinationInterceptor>
           </destinationInterceptors>
           ...
       </broker>
   </beans>
```

Using Mqtt.fx software (https://mqttfx.jensd.de/) I'm only able to dequeue from a Topic (BAR). How can I dequeue from a Queue (FOO) to see the messages arrived on it?

I am new tot this and learning about the protocol MQTT and broker Activemq.